# How to trigger shortcode loaded by CSS

Tags: shortcode

My theme has an option to display the tagline in logo area of the header (tagline added using theme Site Identity settings)

Using CSS I can supplement the tagline with additional content (words etc).

```
        /*tagline */
.fl-theme-tagline::before { 
  content: "[post_title] ";
```

}

--- the content can be "blah blah blah or whatever"

it displays the words/character [post_title] but it is not triggering it to load the title.

I checked the shortcode and it does trigger in the content of the post.

any tips on a functions.php or other solution to this?

thanks

Comment: You can’t do this with CSS, that’s for sure. Whether it’s possible with functions.php depends on how the theme implemented the logo area. Which theme are you using? Third party themes are off topic here, you should contact the theme author for support if you’re not using one of the default themes.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you'd need to do is load the CSS along with the shortcode, as part of the shortcode so that you can pull the same attribute. There's really no way to pass a variable value across to the style.css file.  Is it your custom shortcode?